# Python count and group 0's and 1's within every column

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

Three columns A, B, and C are populated by 0's and 1's. I need the count summary but grouped by the same values within each column which is 0 and 1 using python. Thanks

Here's the sample data and output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Apply `pd.value_counts` to generate a cross table of unique value counts:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1]*7, 'B': [1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0], 'C': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]})

df.apply(pd.value_counts)
#    A  B  C
# 0  7  9  8
# 1  7  5  6
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are only 0/1 one option is to compute the sum of 1s and it's difference to the dataframe length:

```
pd.DataFrame([(s:=df.sum()), len(df)-s], index=[1,0])
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
1  7  5  6
0  7  9  8
```

Comment: NB requires python 3.8+

Comment: Yes :) or split it in two lines